# Complex SQL Query returns not a group by expression error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a very complex query -

```
SELECT
    ' '                                       AS object_type,
    ROWNUM                                    AS object_pri_key_1,
    collected_count                           AS object_pri_key_2,
    total_count                               AS object_pri_key_3,
    'COLLECTED'                               object_data,
    0                                         AS version_no,
    0                                         AS modification_no,
    'ESAF031002'                                login_id,
    progress_color                            text_1,
    dpd                                       text_2,
    ' '                                       text_3,
    ' '                                       text_4,
    ' '                                       text_5,
    ' '                                       text_6,
    ' '                                       text_7,
    ' '                                       text_8,
    ' '                                       text_9,
    ' '                                       text_10,
    ' '                                       is_active,
    ' '                                       pw_session_id,
    sysdate                                   device_create_timestamp,
    sysdate                                   device_modify_timestamp,
    'Y'                                       AS rec_sync_status,
    to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS rec_sync_timestamp,
    ''                                        AS lead_error
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            decode(seq, 1, 'DPD (1-30)', 2, 'DPD (31-60)',
                   3, 'DPD (61-80)', 4, 'DPD (81-90)', 5,
                   'DPD (>90)') AS dpd,
            cnt                 total_count,
            0                   collected_count,
            0                   collected_total_percentage,
            0                   total_amount,
            0                   amount_collected,
            0                   collected_amount_percentage,
            '#00695c'           AS progress_color,
            seq
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    emp_id,
                    nvl(dpd, 0) dpd,
                    COUNT(1)    cnt,
                    1           seq
                FROM
                    vw_loan_details
                WHERE
                    nvl(dpd, 0) BETWEEN 1 AND 30
                GROUP BY
                    emp_id,
                    dpd
                UNION
                SELECT
                    emp_id,
                    nvl(dpd, 0) dpd,
                    COUNT(1)    cnt,
                    2           seq
                FROM
                    vw_loan_details
                WHERE
                    nvl(dpd, 0) BETWEEN 31 AND 60
                GROUP BY
                    emp_id,
                    dpd
                UNION
                SELECT
                    emp_id,
                    nvl(dpd, 0) dpd,
                    COUNT(1)    cnt,
                    3           seq
                FROM
                    vw_loan_details
                WHERE
                    nvl(dpd, 0) BETWEEN 61 AND 80
                GROUP BY
                    emp_id,
                    dpd
                UNION
                SELECT
                    emp_id,
                    nvl(dpd, 0) dpd,
                    COUNT(1)    cnt,
                    4           seq
                FROM
                    vw_loan_details
                WHERE
                    nvl(dpd, 0) BETWEEN 81 AND 90
                GROUP BY
                    emp_id,
                    dpd
                UNION
                SELECT
                    emp_id,
                    nvl(dpd, 0) dpd,
                    COUNT(1)    cnt,
                    5           seq
                FROM
                    vw_loan_details
                WHERE
                    nvl(dpd, 0) > 0
                GROUP BY
                    emp_id,
                    dpd
            )
        WHERE
            emp_id IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    emp_id
                FROM
                    vw_emp_co
                WHERE
                    branch_code IN (
                        SELECT
                            column_value
                        FROM
                            TABLE ( get_emp_branch_code('ESAF031002') )
                    )
                    AND emp_type IN (
                        SELECT
                            view_data
                        FROM
                            tb_emp_type
                        WHERE
                            emp_type = 'I'
                    )
                    AND ( ( emp_id = (
                        CASE
                            WHEN 'Collection Officer' IN ( 'Collection Officer', 'Field Executive' ) THEN
                                'ESAF031002'
                            ELSE
                                ' '
                        END
                    ) )
                          OR 1 = (
                        CASE
                            WHEN 'Collection Officer' NOT IN ( 'Collection Officer', 'Field Executive' ) THEN
                                1
                            ELSE
                                0
                        END
                    ) )
                GROUP BY
                    seq, decode(seq, 1, 'DPD (1-30)', 2, 'DPD (31-60)',
                                3, 'DPD (61-80)', 4, 'DPD (81-90)', 5,
                                'DPD (>90)'), '#00695c'
                                  -- order by seq
            )
    );
```

In the query I am getting error -
`ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression" *Cause:     *Action: Error at Line: 111 Column: 21`

I have tried everything but I am unable to debug it (this code is not my and I can't contact the owner that is why I am posting it here)

I am unable to find why I am getting this not a group by expression error.

Comment: Remove the last GROUP BY clause, entirely. There are no aggregates there, so - why did you use it? If you need to fetch distinct values, then use SELECT DISTINCT, not GROUP BY.

Comment: Looks like a parentheses error... you appear to be wanting to do a group by  a parent block (though you'd even then need to aggregate `cnt`) but have it nested too deep in those parentheses, so it's actually being applied to the wrong block. Format your SQL with proper indentation so that each block is clearly distinct and don't use unnecessary parentheses and it'll be easier to catch these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that in a `GROUP BY` clause a column is referenced that is not in the `SELECT` clause. If you can't find which one, then break the select into chunks and run them one by one to see which one errors out - the way your select is organised this should be pretty straightforward. Or check each of the `GROUP BY` clauses and check if the columns are referenced.

The most likely candidate is the last inner query. The statement

```
                GROUP BY
                    seq, decode(seq, 1, 'DPD (1-30)', 2, 'DPD (31-60)',
                                3, 'DPD (61-80)', 4, 'DPD (81-90)', 5,
                                'DPD (>90)'), '#00695c'
                                  -- order by seq
```

is part of the query starting with:

```
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    emp_id
                FROM
                    vw_emp_co
```

There is no column `seq` in that select clause so this should error out with a "not a group by expression" error.

However, that group by is not needed in that last select and neither is the `DISTINCT` keyword - both will just impact the subquery result (and be more costly) but not the result of the `emp_id IN (<subquery>)` clause. The easiest fix is to just remove the `GROUP BY` clause above.

Comment: You don't need to select GROUP BY columns. (But you need to GROUP BY selected columns, unless they are arguments to aggregate functions.) https://dbfiddle.uk/Opk6GFfC

Comment: BTW, doesn't the optimizer remove unnecessary group by/distinct in subqueries?

Comment: Good point abt the optimizer, I'm still a fan of removing it even if it doesn't make a different in performance

Comment: Agreed, I'd remove it too.